# Getting a negative pageY value when clicking a label in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting a negative value when reading the pageY value for the mouse if I click a label of a radio when using IE11.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.nodeName + ' : ' + event.pageY);
});
// outputs: 
// LABEL : 24
// INPUT : -226
```

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/f45Ug/4/

Other browsers return the same number for input and label as expected.

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: I think the problem could be isolated to jsfiddle. If you resize the height of the result window and click again you'll see the value changes. I suggest you set up a page on your computer and test there

Comment: Maybe related: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/856583/ie11-click-event-has-strange-illogical-screenx-screeny-clientx-clienty-pagex-pagey-coordinates

Comment: The problem is that label and input should get the same pageY value as they are basically triggering the same event (bubbling). A. Wolff, yes, it might be related as I'm getting the same strange coordinates but in another way.